# Selecting inner text of XML nodes and adding to list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, selectnodes

I have the following XML file called file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cache-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config">
   <defaults>
      <serializer>pof</serializer>
   </defaults>
    <caching-scheme-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>broadcast-data|position</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>broadcast</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>broadcast-data|position-audit</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>broadcast-remote</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>broadcast-data|trade</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>broadcast-remote</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
    </caching-scheme-mapping>
</cache-config>
```

I'm trying to get the inner text of all the cache names, which exist under each cache-mapping node, and put them all in a list. I have this Model.cs class to do that.

```
class Model
{
    private XmlDocument cacheFile = new XmlDocument();
    private List<string> cacheNames = new List<string>();
    private int nameCount = 0;


    public Model()
    {
        this.loadNames();
    }

    public void loadNames()
    {
        try //exception handling
        {
            cacheFile.Load("../../resources/file.xml");

        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File not found!");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Invalid path!");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception thrown!");
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        //get cache names
        XmlNodeList nodes = cacheFile.SelectNodes("/cache-config/caching-scheme-mapping/cache-mapping");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string name = node.FirstChild.InnerText;
            cacheNames.Add(name);
            nameCount++;

        }

    }
    //accessors
    public List<string> getCacheNames()
    {
        return cacheNames;
    }
    public int getNameCount()
    {
        return nameCount;
    }

}
```

However, every time I create a Model object and then check if the List was loaded up, it tells me the list is empty! It appears as though the foreach loop never actually runs, or as if the program can't find the nodes I'm specifying. Please help.

Comment: Any reason you have to use `XmlDocument` instead of LINQ to XML? The latter is generally much more pleasant to use...

Comment: You should step through it with the debugger.  I'm going to hazard a guess your `nodes` list is empty as you're ignoring the namespace of your elements.  As @JonSkeet suggests, `XDocument` would be much easier to work with here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm new to .NET, so I was just following some MSDN documentation, which used `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LINQ to XML, this is really quite simple:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config";            

var doc = XDocument.Load("../../resources/file.xml");

cacheNames = doc.Descendants(ns + "cache-name").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

You don't need to keep a separate count of items, you can get this from the list:

```
cacheNames.Count;
```

As an aside, idiomatic C# uses [pascal casing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) for methods and properties, so if you stuck to this your methods would start with a capital letter - e.g. `GetCacheNames`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been puzzling many and has been asked many times here in SO. Your XML has *default namespace* here :

```
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
```

Descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace, unless otherwise specified (using explicit namespace prefix or having local default namespace that point to different namespace URI). Using `XmlDocument` you can use `XmlNamespaceManager` to register prefix to namespace URI mapping, and use the registered prefix properly in your XPath query, for example :

```
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsMgr.AddNamespace("d", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config");
var xpath = "/d:cache-config/d:caching-scheme-mapping/d:cache-mapping";
XmlNodeList nodes = cacheFile.SelectNodes(xpath, nsMgr);
```

Anyway, if you have just started this, switching to newer class `XDocument` would be a better option.